Exporting Data to Tables from PNP Powershell
I'm trying to collect Bucket IDs from a number of MS Planner Plans into a CSV. When the script is run on its own in a single instance of powershell it pulls nine lines of info. How can I get that properly rolled out into a table?
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Group.siteurl -Interactive

   # Pull Plan ID
   $groupname = Get-PnPMicrosoft365Group -identity $Group.groupname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
   $plannerid = Get-PnPPlannerPlan -Group $Group.groupname -Identity $Group.planTitle | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Title
   $bucketids = Get-PnPPlannerBucket -Group $group.groupname -Plan $group.planTitle | select-object -ExpandProperty Id

   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
           GroupName = $groupname
           PlannerName = $plannerid
           BucketIds = $bucketids
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null 
}
$table | Export-Csv -Path "$filesystempath\Pull Plan IDs\output-buckets.csv" -NoTypeInformation

The way it is currently, the Group Name and Planner Name show up properly, but the bucket id shows up in the CSV as "System.Object[]"

Since each plan can have multiple associated buckets, use another loop for them:
$table = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Group.siteurl -Interactive

   # Pull Plan ID
   $groupname = Get-PnPMicrosoft365Group -identity $Group.groupname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
   $plannerid = Get-PnPPlannerPlan -Group $Group.groupname -Identity $Group.planTitle | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Title

   foreach ($bucket in Get-PnPPlannerBucket -Group $group.groupname -Plan $group.planTitle) {
       [pscustomobject]@{
           GroupName = $groupname
           PlannerName = $plannerid
           BucketIds = $bucket.Id
       }
    }
}

$table | Export-Csv -Path "$filesystempath\Pull Plan IDs\output-buckets.csv" -NoTypeInformation


Your general logic is working fine. Tested with simpler inputs:
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

for ($i=0;$i -lt 5;$i++){
    $newrow = [pscustomobject]@{
        var = $i
        name = ($i+1)
    }
    $table.Add($newRow) | out-null 
}

$table | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\output-buckets.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Which leads to my assumption, that although you are expanding the properties, there are still objects inside. My first guess is that there are multiple objects you are getting bucketids of.
Using simpler values to test your scripts not only makes our work here easier but could also help you get around what issue your script is having. ;-)

Okay so if I run the get-pnpplannerbucket cmdlet on its own I get a nice layout of info in a table format. How can I have that as part of the table export?

@Justin Depends on what you want - CSV is not really able to display objects, so you have to work around that. Put attributes in additional columns or merge information into one column.
